# Talend Open Studio 7.1 : tJavaFlex output issue

Tags: arraylist, talend

I'm asking for your help,I'm facing a problem with the tJavaFlex component.

```
editorName ;ProductName ;end_date_resorption_versions;end_date_supported_versions ;end_date_recommended_versions
EditorA;PN_A;31/03/2017,31/03/2017,31/03/2017,31/03/2017,31/03/2017,31/03/2017;null;null 
EditorA;PN_A;30/06/2024;null;30/06/2024
EditorA;PN_A;30/11/2020,30/06/2017;null;null 
EditorA;PN_A;null;30/06/2024;null 
EditorA;PN_A ;null;null;null 
EditorA;PN_A;30/11/2020,30/11/2020;null;null 
EditorB;PN_B;18/05/2017,31/03/2017,31/01/20;null;null 
EditorB;PN_B;03/06/2024;01/02/2020;30/06/2024
EditorB;PN_B;23/12/2014      ;null;null 
EditorB;PN_B;null;01/02/2020;30/06/2020
EditorB;PN_B;null;null;null 
EditorB;PN_B;12/12/2012,31/12/2020;null;13/01/2020
```

[image: Query]

As u can see there are list of date (string format) in same column.

What i want to do ==> it's to find the min date for each column (not row)

[image: Result expected]

My approach is this :

1. By column, store all values in an array
2. convert ListString to ListDate
3. Find Date min in each ListDate

I thought the best way to do that was to use the tJavaFlex component.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Start Code :**

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// Array for end_date_resorption_versions
List<String> myStringList_edrv = new ArrayList<>();
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();

// Array for end_date_supported_versions
List<String> myStringList_edsv = new ArrayList<>();
List<Date> dates_edsv = new ArrayList<>();

// Array for end_date_recommended_versions
List<String> myStringList_edrev = new ArrayList<>();
List<Date> dates_edrev = new ArrayList<>();
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**main code :**

if (row4.end_date_resorption_versions == null ){
        row4.end_date_resorption_versions  = "31/12/2099";
    }
if (row4.end_date_supported_versions == null ){     
        row4.end_date_supported_versions   = "31/12/2099";
    }
if (row4.end_date_recommended_versions == null) {
        row4.end_date_recommended_versions = "31/12/2099";
    }
// populating data : 
myStringList_edrv.addAll(Arrays.asList(row4.end_date_resorption_versions.split(",")));
myStringList_edsv.addAll(Arrays.asList(row4.end_date_supported_versions.split(",")));
myStringList_edrev.addAll(Arrays.asList(row4.end_date_recommended_versions.split(",")));
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**end code :**

// transform ListString to ListDate : end_date_resorption_versions
for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringList_edrv.size(); i++) {
    dates.add(sdf.parse(myStringList_edrv.get(i)));
    }
// transform ListString to ListDate : end_date_supported_versions
for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringList_edsv.size(); i++) {
    dates_edsv.add(sdf.parse(myStringList_edsv.get(i)));
    }
// transform ListString to ListDate : end_date_recommended_versions
for (int i = 0 ; i < myStringList_edrev.size(); i++) {
    dates_edrev.add(sdf.parse(myStringList_edrev.get(i)));
    }

// getMinDate : end_date_resorption_versions
row6.out_date_edrv  =   sdf.format(Collections.min(dates));
// getMinDate : end_date_supported_versions
row6.out_date_edsv  =   sdf.format(Collections.min(dates_edsv));
// getMinDate : end_date_recommended_versions
row6.out_date_edrev =   sdf.format(Collections.min(dates_edrev));

row6.out_editor_name = row4.editor_name;
row6.out_product_name = row4.product_name;

System.out.println("out_date_edrv => " + row6.out_date_edrv);
System.out.println("out_date_edsv => " + row6.out_date_edsv);
System.out.println("out_date_edrev => " + row6.out_date_edrev);
```

all my values are null, while the results present in the system.out.println are good

[image: null value]

my job design is :

tPostgresqlInput----row4(Main)----tJavaFlex_1----row6(Main)----tLogRow

some help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include data directly in your question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about images with code/data.

Comment: @Slimak i edited my post with csv data

Comment: I embedded the screenshots in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that java code. Here's a solution using only Talend components which has the advantage of being easier to maintain should your requirement change.
[image]

I start by normalizing your date columns; if only `end_date_resorption_versions` can contain a list of dates, then you can skip `tNormalize_2` and `tNormalize_3` which normalize `end_date_supported_versions` and `end_date_recommended_versions` respectively.
[image]

the `tMap_1` is probably not needed, I use it to convert the "null" literal to `null`, since I copy pasted your sample data in a file for my test, otherwise the following conversion would fail.

[image]

`tConvertType_1` then converts the date string to Date type, by checking the option "Auto cast", and setting the schema as follows:
[image]

Finally, `tAggregateRow_1` will group on the `editorName` and `ProductName` columns and get the minimum date from each date column:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ibrahim Mezouar, 

Thank you very much. It's working properly, and it is easier to maintain.

There will be a little frustration left from not being able to do it with the tjavaFlex ;)

PS: Thanks for embedding the images, I wasn't allowed to do it because you have to have reputation points

Answer (score 0):

No explanation, just a nasty hack : Try to insert a ***tFlowToIterate*** before your *tJavaFlex* and feed the *tJavaFlex* with an *iterate* flow instead of a *main* flow (See pictures below).

Here, for some reason my *tJavaFlex* only reads *null* values from the input *main* flow

[image: tJavaFlex reading only 'null' values from main flow]

But it manages to read the exact same data when provided through an *iterate* flow.
Note that as long as your input data flow isn't renamed (*row4* in my example), you won't have to touch the code in your tJavaFlex.

[image: tJavaFlex being able to read from an iterate flow]

I have absolutely no clue on why nor when tJavaFlex wouldn't cope well with flows of type main, and I find that rather frustrating. I would surely appreciate if a talend guru could give me an explanation !